# How to fix loading images again in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am using images sprite. All images saved in one my_images_sprite.png.
In **Chrome**, when page is loaded (all images is loaded and shown), if I mouse over Image on page, It image begin loading again.

EDIT:

```
<a href="/subscribe" id="download-btn">
              <span class="big">Click</span>                 
              <span class="icon"></span>
</a>

CSS: 
#download-btn {
display: block;
width: 192px;
height: 61px;
position: relative;
cursor: pointer;
text-decoration: none;  
background-image: url(http://localhost:5000/assets/icons-sc0fd629fcc.png);
background-repeat-x: no-repeat;
background-repeat-y: no-repeat;
background-attachment: initial;
background-position-x: 0px;
background-position-y: -2082px;
background-origin: initial;
background-clip: initial;
background-color: initial;
color: #581B89;
}
```

How to fix this?

In Firefox all works correct.

Comment: It would help if you were to share some code!

Comment: Do you have any code, you would like to share?

Comment: Have you really written out all this, or is this just copied from Chrome web inspector?

Comment: For css I use scss. It i copied from Chrome web inspector

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking it has something to do with you setting the background-image twice with different urls:

```
background: url(/assets/icons-sc0fd629fcc.png) 0 -2082px no-repeat;
background-image: url(http://localhost:5000/assets/icons-sc0fd629fcc.png);
```

Remove the `background-image` property and you should be fine!

Comment: I have mistaken, My css without background: url(/assets/icons-sc0fd629fcc.png) 0 -2082px no-repeat;. I have fixed this in my question.